# making a filter with ajax from a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a model where I store some "views", but in some part of my code, I only want to get the ones which kind value is equal to home.

I need it to be done by Ajax.

The code below already gets all the elements of the database, but I just need those with the **kind** attribute equal to **home**:

```
 'onTabShow':function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    console.log(index);
                    if (index == 1){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: '/userpanel/webapi/viewlist',
                            dataFilter:(kind,home),//this doesnt work, there has to be a way to properly do it

                        }).done(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        })      
                    }
                }
              });
```

this is the model code

```
var TIPOS_MEDIA = 'video serie picture sound live home'.split(' ');

const View = new Schema({
   viewname: String,
   component: String,
   componenturl: String,
   screenshot: String,
   price: Number,
   kind: { type: String, enum: TIPOS_MEDIA, default: 'video' }, 
   options: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Option' }],
   platform: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Platform' },
});

ViewModel = mongoose.model('View', View);

module.exports = ViewMode
```

in case of being needed this is the webapi code

```
router.get('/userpanel/webapi/viewlist', function(req, res) {
      View.find({})
      .populate("options",'optionname')
      .populate("platform")
      .exec(function(err, views) {
          if (err) {
              res.send(err);
          } else {
            var _views = [];
            for (var i = views.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var view = {
                    _id:views[i]._id,
                    viewname:views[i].viewname,
                    component:views[i].component,
                    componenturl:views[i].componenturl,
                    screenshot:views[i].screenshot,
                    price:views[i].price,
                    kind:views[i].kind,
                    platform:views[i].platform.platformname,
                };
                var optionnames = "";
                for (var i2 = views[i].options.length - 1; i2 >= 0; i2--) {
                    optionnames = optionnames +    views[i].options[i2].optionname + ","
                }
                view.optionnames = optionnames;
                _views.push(view);
            }

              res.json({
                data:_views
              });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Could you format your code properly please (below "this is the model code"). For your question: could you provide an example JSON reponse that you get?

Comment: this is it https://imgur.com/iv2libT its just a console log of response, but thats what i need, in the screen shot there is 3  objects but if i had a filter it should just to be 2 of them, since one them doesnt have his kind value equal to home

Comment: could you take the object in your console, define it as global, use JSON.stringify(<your global variable>) and provide the result of that (properly formatted pelase).